# Кастомное окно EditorWindow выдает ошибку "The same field name is serialized multiple times in the class or its parent class."

Tags: c#, unity3d, сериализация

Не понимаю с чём может быть связана эта ошибка :

```
The same field name is serialized multiple times in the class or its parent class. This is not supported: Base(PlacementObjects) m_Pos
```

`Vector2 m_Pos` используется всего пару раз в коде :

```
...
public class PlacementObjects : EditorWindow {
   protected Vector2 m_Pos;
   ...
   [MenuItem("Window/PlacementObjects")]
   static void Init() {
        PlacementObjects window = (PlacementObjects)EditorWindow.GetWindow(typeof(PlacementObjects));
        window.Show();
    }
    void OnGUI()
    {
       /* код */
       m_Pos = GUILayout.BeginScrollView(m_Pos, false, true,GUILayout.Width(LeftSection.width), GUILayout.Height(LeftSection.height));
       /* код */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все на самом деле очевидно из текста ошибки: имя `m_Pos` сериализируется 2+ раза. Если это делаете не вы, то это делает внутренний код Unity.

Дизассемблируем код класса EditorWindow и видим, что в нем действительно уже определена переменная `m_Pos`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Компилятор не ругается просто потому что ваша реализация перекрывает это имя, так что с точки зрения языка тут нет проблем, а вот сам Unity пытается сериализовать все переменные во всей иерархии классов.

---

TL;DR

Нужно переименовать переменную `m_Pos` во что угодно другое, например, `_m_Pos`.